# iOS gesture recognizer only starts after user touches view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIPinchGestureRecognizer that i have added to a custom UIView which is subsequently added as a subview of my main view. For some reason, the pinch gesture doesn't get detected when the user first attempts to pinch, but does for any later attempts. See the code below, the user must touch the view at least once before the nslog is printed out when the user later pinches.

Declaration:

```
        self.pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandAction:)];
        self.pinchGesture.scale = 0.0;
        self.pinchGesture.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:self.pinchGesture];
```

Action:

```
-(void)expandAction:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"pinch detected");
    //stop reminding user
    [self stopTimer:self.pinchExpandTimer];
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.0
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations: ^{
                         [self.pinchCircle1 removeFromSuperview];
                         [self.pinchCircle2 removeFromSuperview];
                     }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
    //calculate progress
    CGFloat progress = MIN(sender.scale/5, 1.0);
    [self setPinchAnimationWithProgress:progress];
 }
```

Delegate:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark UIGestureRecognizer Delegate

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Basically, it feels like the user must "select" the view then do the gesture in order for it to be picked up. I have tried enabling user interaction on the view and/or setting first responder but it still doesn't work. There are other gesture recognizers in use in this view if that has any effect, but I don't think that it should. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have used a `UIView animateWithDuration` block without actually animating anything (`duration` and `delay` are both 0) ?

Comment: It cancels any animation that is in progress on the elements the new animation affects. In this case, I want to remove the items that are being animated if the pinch gesture is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Issue was that I was setting the scale property on my UIPinchGestureRecognizer right after initializing it. This might be a bug in Apple's code.